# how to reposition dataTables filter pagination and information elements in html

Tags: jquery

I am using `dataTables` `jquery` to help me with pagination, and search. But I want the search box to be in the top-center of the website, and pagination to be at the bottom-center of the website. (information should be at the bottom right)

I have tried using the below in my `css` but still unable to get the desired results

```
/* Tried this first*/
.dataTables_filter {
    text-align: 'center';
}

/* Tried this second.. This wouldnt even bring the elements to the left of the screen. let alone to the center*/
.dataTables_filter {
    float: 'left'
};
```

I have also tried `dom` manipulation to position the elements, but still unsuccessful.

```
// view_student section.
$(document).ready(function(){
// Pagination
$('#id_view_student_table').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    'lengthChange': false,
    'language':{
        'search':'<i class="fas fa-search"></i>',
        'searchPlaceholder': 'Search records'
    },
    'dom': '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"ip>',
});
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr({'class': 'search-input'});
});
```

Also, as I am using `font awesome` within the label (as you can see it in the `jquery`). is it possible to change the positioning? To have the image appear behind the search box instead of before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For center your search,

```
 div.dataTables_wrapper  div.dataTables_filter {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

try this css code. And for pagination and info I edited the live code sample. make sure to set `float:none` and `text-align:center`.
Sample live code can found here - [datatable search option](http://live.datatables.net/bubarecu/1/edit)

To change the position of the serch icon just use the css tag like below,

```
'<i style="float:right" class="fas fa-search"></i>'
```

[image: Search icon on the right]

Comment: Thanks for this, it does work. But I was wondering if you are able to help with the positioning of the `font awesome` image to be behind the search box instead of infront? (infront being the default)

Comment: let me check on that. behind means, you want after the search box, correct ?

Comment: That is correct. I want it after the search box. :)

Comment: Just check the update. It is working fine with my datatable version. I hope yours too. If that is working make sure to mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: Awesome! I had to perform some tweaks like adding margins of 2px, but overall it works! :)